# Running Scipy using sparkmooc Vagrant box

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I did Spark [mooc course in EDX](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-big-data-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs100-1x). And I wanted to work further in this setup. I could create code and run few things. But can't update python in it. I wanted to install python package `scipy`.

I followed the instruction given in group, on installing Anaconda. And I could install anaconda in SparkVM. Please find the screenshot below.
[image]

But when I try to run when I try to run any code that required "pandas" or "scipy", it can't import it. Please find the screenshot below. Can anybody please help me.

[image]

Even though this question is not exactly relevant here. But still asking as in case somebody also did the same course and could update Sparkvm.
 Please find below the screenshot of my SparkVM details.

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that IPython running through Anaconda's launcher?

Comment: Thanks Leb for your comment! But not sure if IPython is running through anaconda launcher or not. I followed all the steps given in this link, except for the optional about "IPython Notebook directory". If you can tell me how to check it, I'll be extremely grateful. The link: https://gist.github.com/evrial/165965f6b86c386cf309

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with the "env PATH". In IPython type `!PATH` is it listing Anaconda3 on there? Because modules loaded on basic Python will not be automatically be used on other Python distribution (i.e. Anaconda).

Comment: Hi Leb, if I type '!PATH' then it's saying '/bin/sh: 1: PATH: not found'. If you see the link I shared, they asked to change the path, and I did it and it ran without any error.

Comment: Yea I got the same error on my VM. I use a different (private) VM to get it running, but I know for sure that the IPython session isn't running using Anaconda's distribution or not loading it properly. It's reverting to regular Python and that's why you're unable to load those packages. I'd look into other config files in that and see what's wrong. You restarted the notebook after you changed the path right? If so, maybe restart the VM?

Comment: Thanks Leb! The problem has been solved. You had been extremely patient and helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to ignore Anaconda and install `SciPy` globally. Either from shell:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install -y python-scipy
```

or from IPython notebook:

```
!sudo aptitude update
!sudo aptitude install -y python-scipy
```

Since system packages are usually outdated you may prefer to use `pip`:

```
!pip install --user scipy
```

To properly configure Anaconda you can edit `/home/vagrant/spark_notebook.py` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON` / `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` variables:

```
setenv('PYSPARK_PYTHON', '/path/to/anaconda/bin/python', overwrite=False)
setenv('PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON', '/path/to/anaconda/bin/ipython')
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks a lot! I actually installed just SciPy as well. But not from IPython itself. When I ran it, it worked. Thanks again.